# paper-dropdown searchable / filterable

Tags: polymer

Is there any component like the paper-dropdown element with any extra line to search and filter the items of the drop down? In Jquery there are tons of such elements.

It would be really cool if polymer has something like that to or if anyone can give me a hint, how I can achieve that on my own.

Thanks!!

Comment: paper-dropdown is a wrapper for paper-dropdown-menu  https://github.com/pushkar8723/paper-dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Check out [@addyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3151817/addyo)'s `<typeahead-country>` element.

https://github.com/addyosmani/typeahead-country

You could fork it and change the [country list](https://github.com/addyosmani/typeahead-country/blob/gh-pages/src/typeahead-country.html#L63) to be whatever elements you need.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is inside paper-listbox add a paper-input and then connect its value with a filer that repeats paper-item for dropdown. You will also need to stop propagation of events that happens on paper-input.

**HTML**

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Fruits">
   <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="data-value" selected="{{fruit}}">
      <paper-input class="paperdropdownsearch" label="Search" value="{{key}}"
            on-tap="_stopEventPropagation"
            on-keydown="_stopEventPropagation"
            on-keyup="_stopEventPropagation"></paper-input>
       <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{allFruits}}" filter="{onMatch(key)}}">
             <paper-item data-value="{{item}}">{{item}}</paper-item>
       </template>
   </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
   onMatch: function (key) {
               if (!key) {
                   return null;
               } else {
                  try {
                     key = key.toLowerCase();
                    } catch (err) {}

                  return function (item) {
                    var curr = item.toLowerCase();
                    if (curr.search(key) >= 0) {
                      return true;
                    }
                 };
              }
           },
    _stopEventPropagation: function(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            },
```

**Demo**
http://embed.plnkr.co/ax9gjxonA3rC8K4Xr2LL/